# How to stop Android Studio from running my gradle task when syncing project with Gradle files?

Tags: android, gradle

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#sync-files),

> When you make changes to the build configuration files in your
> project, Android Studio requires that you sync your project files so
> that it can import your build configuration changes and run some
> checks to make sure your configuration won't create build errors.

my **build.gradle** for app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    //...  <--modified here
}

task myTask() {
    println 'doing something...'
    //time-consuming operations which may takes 16s or more
    println 'done'
}
```

I just found that it runs `myTask` every time I modified the `build.gradle` for app, even if I didn't change it.

Is that a normal operation when *running some checks to make sure your configuration won't create build errors*? If that is, how can I make the task not run when syncing?

**Environment**:
Android Studio 3.1.3 with gradle-4.9-bin.zip

Comment: Each modification triggers the Sync. This is normal. Gradle file modifications usually occurs not so many often, so it's normally not a problem. Maybe your Gradle file is build using "wrong idea"? I mean: if you should edit it so often, are you sure it's the good way?

Comment: I thought there is some method that marks a task as *no-need-to-check*. So the task marked with that won't be executed when syncing. I can guarantee that `myTask` won't create build errors.

Comment: You could create a "Build Variant" called (for example) "NoTaskDebug" and in your Gradle file procedure use a check against THAT Variant. So you can quickly change Variant to bypass that IF condition. Screenshot of "Build Variants" Palette/Window: https://antoniocappiellocomblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/build-variants.png

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Your task does not run at all, it is just configured.**

Gradle distinguishes between the *configuration phase* and the *execution phase*. On each invocation, every task is configured, but only the tasks passed to Gradle and their task dependencies are executed. As IntelliJ / AndroidStudio invokes Gradle on sync, every task is configured on sync. When you define a task in Gradle, the closure you pass is used for configuration. Only task actions (internal functionality), `doFirst` and `doLast` closures are executed during *execution phase*. For your custom task, you should put your functionality into such a closure:

```
task example {
    println 'Configuration' 
    doLast {
        println 'Execution' 
    } 
}
```